# add a dot to a string using C

Tags: c

i want to add  "/." to a file name, for example,
i have file name "abc", i want to get a name "abc/.abc",
how to do it in C?
strcpy("/.",name) and strcat("/.",name) returned segmentation fault.

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. When you ask homework questions, you need to show what you've tried so far (actual code), and explain what didn't work like you expected. We'll be happy to try and help you figure it out, but you shouldn't expect to get actual answers here. You need to do the work yourself in order to actually learn anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first parameter to `strcat` must be a *modifiable* string with enough space allocated to hold the resulting string and the terminating zero byte. The first parameter to `strcpy` must point to allocated, *modifiable* memory with sufficient space to hold the resulting copy of the string and the terminating zero byte. In both of your examples, you have passed a constant as the first parameter.

Here's some example code to do what you want:

```
char* SlashDotter(const char* in)
{ // turn <string> into <string>/.<string> -- caller must free returned string
 char *out = malloc(strlen(in)*2 + 3); // two copies of input, /, ., and nul
 strcpy(out, in);
 strcat(out, "/.");
 strcat(out, in);
 return out;
}
```

Comment: Please don't answer homework questions with code. The poster doesn't learn anything except how to ask others to do their work, and then we end up trying to fix the messes they make later by not learning anything now. Ask them to post what they've tried so far and explain what didn't work as expected, and then guide them in the direction of figuring it out. Answering non-questions like this hoping to garner more rep is a bad idea, and won't benefit you in the long run. Thanks. :) I'd suggest that you delete your answer as quickly as possible, or at least edit it to not provide the actual code.

Comment: I don't think trying to guide someone to a solution fits the SE question and answer format. I'm not hoping to garner more rep, I'm hoping to place a high-quality answer on the site rather than lower quality discussion answers.

Comment: just to clarify, the question i asked wasn't the real homework question, and I did learn from the answer given by david schwartz. Thanks again

Comment: It may fit the Q&A format. It doesn't benefit the asker in the long run, though. I didn't downvote because technically your answer wasn't wrong; it doesn't serve the best interests of the person who asked, though, and it definitely doesn't benefit future students who find it and use it to answer homework assignments without understanding it. You're entitled to your opinion, of course, but I have to ask if you found the answer elsewhere and just copied and pasted it, or if you wrote it based on what you've learned before?

Comment: @Ken I'm still new to this site myself (newer than David there), and while I agree that one should avoid writing code that the poster can simply copy and paste for their homework, I'd hate to find out that homework answers featuring code is taboo. I think it's illustrative to provide some well-commented, working and non-working examples of the concepts explained in the answer that the poster can then compare and contrast for understanding. This poster in particular could benefit from some examples of typical misuses of strcpy and strcat with explanations of why they failed and how to fix them.

Comment: @James: My last comment. :) I agree that explanations of why they failed and how to fix them are useful, **if** the asker posts their efforts to use them. This question didn't, and giving an answer based on their knowing the words `strcpy` and `strcat` isn't helpful. My opinion is that they should show at least *some* effort, and then we can guide them in making that effort work. Think of this: if you want to be a weight lifter, and I offer to help you train by picking up anything that weighs more than a pound (or kilo), how well do you compete in the next contest lifting things on your own?

Answer (score 1):

asprintf() can be used to allocate a string and fill it's contents.

on linux systems "man asprintf" will give you a description of how the function works otherwise use google to get help from other places.